# SQL Creating a stored proc for returning age bands

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a table called Person that contain a field called PersonAge. I need to group the ages by age bands ie '12 and under', '13-17', '18-25', '25 and over' and return this resultset using a stored procedure.

Ideally I need to get returned 2 fields , 'Age Band', 'Total' like so

```
Age band         Total 
12 and under     5
13 - 17          8
18 - 25          7
25 and over      10
```

Comment: @Mich, your "18-25" and "25 and over" ageband overlap.

Comment: @ Lieven Well spotted Lieven, it was a typo in the question as it was late at night (that's my excuse!), I can assure you it's not in the production code...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a table containing your bands:

```
CREATE TABLE agebands
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    lower_bound INT NOT NULL,
    upper_bound INT NOT NULL
)
CREATE INDEX IDX_agebands_bounds ON (lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

Then populate it with your data:

```
INSERT INTO agebands VALUES (1, 0, 12)
INSERT INTO agebands VALUES (2, 13, 17)
INSERT INTO agebands VALUES (3, 18, 24)
INSERT INTO agebands VALUES (4, 25, 199)
```

Then join with it:

```
SELECT
    lower_bound, upper_bound,
    COUNT(*) AS number_of_people
FROM
    persons
    INNER JOIN agebands
        ON person_age BETWEEN lower_bound AND upper_bound
GROUP BY
    lower_bound, upper_bound
ORDER BY
    lower_bound
```

This allows for flexibility in adjusting the bands. Of course, the other answer here using UNION is usable too, which is more appropriate if you can/won't add another table to your database.

Comment: +1 Neat, although for this trivial example I'd argue that the union is easier to maintain then the extra table. After one year, no one remembers that all they have to do is add, delete or change a record in a table without reading the source procedure anyway.

Comment: +1 this is more efficient and maintainable than the union based answer

Comment: That depends entirely on usage. If hit is an oft-used feature for grouping, to group by age bands, and those age-bands are the same, I'd say that adding a form to manipulate such a table is the user-friendly way, instead of having to make sure the code that executes the SQL builds the correct SQL every time. But yes, if this is a one-off or in-one-place type of feature, I'd go with the union as well.

Comment: Very close call between Lievens UNION answer and lassevks extra table approach. I ended up with lassevks extra table approach as it has the added flexibility of allowing the client to alter their own age bands. Many thanks for all your excellent input...

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly!  Never thought of using a join - I had a complicated CTE involved.  I want to use variable age bands stored in another table, so the CASE won't work for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A simple UNION should suffice.

```
SELECT [Ageband] = '12 and under', COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Person
WHERE PersonAge <= 12
UNION ALL SELECT '13-17', COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Person
WHERE PersonAge BETWEEN 13 AND 17
UNION ALL SELECT '18-25', COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Person
WHERE PersonAge BETWEEN 18 AND 25
UNION ALL SELECT '26 and over', COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Person
WHERE PersonAge >= 26
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should give:

```
select count(*), person_age
from (
    select (case 
               when age between 0 and 12 then '12 and under'
               when age between 13 and 17 then '13-17'
               when age between 18 and 25 then '18-15'
               else 'Above 25'
            end) as 'person_age'
    from person)
group by person_age
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you cannot group by a column alias. You'd need to repeat the case statement like this.

```
select count(*), 
case  
    when aged between 0 and 12 then '12 and under'
    when aged between 13 and 17 then '13-17'
    when aged between 18 and 25 then '18-15'
    else 'Above 25' end
from person
group by 
case  
    when aged between 0 and 12 then '12 and under'
    when aged between 13 and 17 then '13-17'
    when aged between 18 and 25 then '18-15'
    else 'Above 25'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tempT table(age int)
declare @temp2 table(age2 varchar(15))

insert into @tempT(age) values(1)
insert into @tempT(age) values(2)
insert into @tempT(age) values(3)
insert into @tempT(age) values(4)
insert into @tempT(age) values(5)
insert into @tempT(age) values(6)
insert into @tempT(age) values(7)
insert into @tempT(age) values(8)
insert into @tempT(age) values(9)
insert into @tempT(age) values(10)
insert into @tempT(age) values(11)

insert into @Temp2
select  case  
when age < 3 then '<3'
when age >= 3 and age < 5 then '>= 3 and < 5'
when age >= 5 then '>=5'
end
from @tempT

select count(*), age2 from @Temp2 
GROUP BY age2
```